# Colobars multiplying each loop

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, colorbar

```
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(9.5, 4), facecolor='w')

for i in range(100):
    h = ax0.hist2d(globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#Row'], globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#Col'], weights=globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#ToA'], bins = GridX1max-GridX1min, range = [(GridX1min, GridX1max), (GridY1min, GridY1max)], norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())
    fig.colorbar(h[3], ax = ax0)

    h = ax1.hist2d(globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#Row'], globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#Col'], weights=globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#ToT[arb]'], bins = GridX1max-GridX1min, range = [(GridX1min, GridX1max), (GridY1min, GridY1max)], norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())
    fig.colorbar(h[3], ax = ax1)

    fig.tight_layout()

    fig.savefig('gridtoatot_frame'+str(i)+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close("all")
plt.show()
```

I am getting this and I can't seem to work out a solution. plt.close("all) and plt.clf() seem to have no effect:

[image]

Each plot should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8PMb.png)

Comment: What exactly are are you trying to do? Your code is plotting a colorbar at every iteration, consequently re-scaling `ax0` and `ax1`.

Comment: Each plot should have only one colorbar beside it how do I get it to stop rescaling? I just want 100 plots.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have added an example of the intended result

Comment: `plt.close()` closes the window, but doesn't clear nor remove the figure.  Try `plt.clf()` to clear the figure at the end of each pass of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have arrived at a solution in this:

```
for i in range(100):
    fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(9.5, 4), facecolor='w')
    h = ax0.hist2d(globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#Row'], globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#Col'], weights=globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#ToA'], bins = GridX1max-GridX1min, range = [(GridX1min, GridX1max), (GridY1min, GridY1max)], norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())
    fig.colorbar(h[3], ax = ax0)

    h = ax1.hist2d(globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#Row'], globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#Col'], weights=globals()['grid1_pulse'+str(i)+'_df']['#ToT[arb]'], bins = GridX1max-GridX1min, range = [(GridX1min, GridX1max), (GridY1min, GridY1max)], norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm())
    fig.colorbar(h[3], ax = ax1)

    fig.tight_layout()

    fig.savefig('gridtoatot_frame'+str(i)+'.png', bbox_inches='tight')
    plt.close()
    fig.clf()
plt.show()
```